# How to change scrolling speeds in the Unity inspector?

Tags: unity

When I'm in the Inspector tab in Unity I cannot realistically use the scroll wheel on my mouse to move up or down in it. Is there a way to change the scroll speed in the Inspector specifically to make it less enormous?

Comment: What makes this unrealistic at present? Mouse wheel scroll deltas are usually an OS setting - have you tried adjusting it there?

Comment: My mouse wheel speed is fine in every other application. It's not a system-wide issue; it's just far too sensitive in the Inspector.